# Plural form of noun before noun for the title of position in organizations

Tags: singular-vs-plural

For naming job tile or position in organizations, I found that sometimes we use plural form of noun for describing another noun. For example

> Corporate Communications Supervisor

and

> Corporate Communication Supervisor

I used NGram and found that **Communications Supervisor** is used more widely than **Communication Supervisor**

[NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Communications%20Supervisor%2CCommunication%20Supervisor&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CCommunications%20Supervisor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CCommunication%20Supervisor%3B%2Cc0)

Is there any rule for when to make the noun ,that is describing another noun, plural or singular?

Answer (score 2):

In your example, the person is probably responsible for more than one type or channel of communication, hence communications.

However, the practice may vary, for example **Student Advisor** is used not **Students Advisor**.